# Create a New User via Form in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to create a page-template on wordpress that allows me to create a new user through a form on the front end of the website. Basically I want it to be laid out like how it currently is on the wordpress admin page but I need to make it work on the frontend.

(Layout would look like this)[wordpress admin create new user page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkYYB.png)

The part that I'm stuck now is, when the user presses submit how can I handle the data and add it into the wordpress db? (Using this https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user)

(Code so far...) -

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Create User
 */

get_header('user'); 
?>

<?php // Start the Loop.
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <div id="left-content">

        <?php  //GET THEME HEADER CONTENT
        theme_title(get_the_title()); ?>    

        <!-- START CONTENT -->
            <div id="content">
                <?php if (woffice_is_user_allowed()) { ?>

                <!-- PHP Create User -->
                <?php
                    function add_user_from_form() {
                       $user_login = $_POST['email'];
                       $first_name = $_POST['fName'];
                       $last_name = $_POST['lName'];
                       $user_email = $_POST['email'];
                       $user_pass = $_POST['pass'];
                       $display_name = "{$first_name} {$last_name}";
                       $role = $_POST['role'];
                       $info = array(
                           'user_login' => $user_login, 
                           'user_pass' =>  $user_pass,
                           'user_email' => $user_email,
                           'display_name' => $display_name,
                           'first_name' => $first_name,
                           'last_name' => $last_name,
                           'role' => $role
                       );
                       $result = wp_insert_user( $info )
                       if ( is_wp_error( $result ) ) {
                          echo $result->get_error_message();
                       } else {
                          echo "Added user {$result}";
                       }
                    } 
                ?>

                <div class="box">
                     <form id="create-user-form" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <input value="" name="fName" id="fName" placeholder="First Name"  required="" type="text">
                                <input value="" name="lName" id="lName" placeholder="Last Name"  required="" type="text">
                                <input value="" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email"  required="" type="text">
                                <input value="" name="pass" id="password" placeholder="Password"  required="" type="Password">
                                <select name="role">
                                    <option value="author">Author</option>
                                    <option value="contributor">Contributor</option>
                                </select>
                                <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn-ser" value="Create New User" style="width:160px !important; padding-left:18px;">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>  
                </div>
                <?php } else { 
                    get_template_part( 'content', 'private' );
                }
                ?>  
            </div>

        </div><!-- END #content-container -->

        <?php theme_scroll_top(); ?>

    </div><!-- END #left-content -->

<?php // END THE LOOP 
endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert the data in the WP db, you can use the WP database API.

You can include the **global wpdb** object in your code to post the form data in your database.

```
global $wpdb;
```

Then use the insert function to post the data in db.

```
<?php $wpdb->insert( $table, $data, $format ); ?>
```

Check this link for more details : https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#INSERT_row[enter link description here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#INSERT_row)

Create a function in your functions.php like below to handle your post data:

```
function my_theme_send_email() {
  if ( isset( $_POST['email-submission'] ) && '1' == $_POST['email-submission'] ) {
    // Send the email...
  } // end if
} // end my_theme_send_email
add_action( 'init', 'my_theme_send_email' );
```

Refer this link as well they have explained very nicely : https://tommcfarlin.com/sending-data-post/

Comment: I already know how to add a custom page template. I'm looking for the actual code to add a user to the wordpress database on submit via the form.

Comment: Sorry, got it wrong previously, I have edited the answer hope this helps.

Comment: This is still not what I am looking for. I need help with creating a submit function that will use wp_create_user function and pass all the variables I have listed above.

Answer (score 0):

Users need a login name for database. Login can be anything. Users do not need to know it, because users can login with email address.

I would use [wp_insert_user()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user).

Example:

```
function add_user_from_form() {
   $now = time();                        // unique number
   $c = chr( ($now % 26) + 65 );         // random letter
   $user_login = $c . strval( $now );    // unique user name
   $first_name = $_POST['fName'];
   $last_name = $_POST['lName'];
   $user_email = $_POST['email'];
   $user_pass = $_POST['pass'];
   $display_name = "{$first_name} {$last_name}";
   /*
       VALIDATE USER DATA BEFORE ADDING TO DATABASE
   */
   $info = array('user_login' => $user_login, 
   'user_pass' =>  $user_pass,
   'user_email' => $user_email,
   'display_name' => $display_name,
   'first_name' => $first_name,
   'last_name' => $last_name);
   $result = wp_insert_user( $info )
   if ( is_wp_error( $result ) ) {
      echo $result->get_error_message();
   } else {
      echo "Added user {$result}";
   }
}
```

Simplest way use this on a page is to create a [template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/) with a different header and process form on the same page.

E.g. Copy page.php to create-user.php and add the template header.
Copy header.php to header-user.php. Replace `get_header()` with
`get_header('user')`.

Edit action on form:

```
<form id="my-registration-form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']">
```

Add my function to the top of header with:

```
if ( 'POST` == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) {
   add_user_from_form();
}
```

You do not need an `action`. You just need to process form.

This does not conform to best practice of using [MVC pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), but it is easy and it will work.

Hope this clarifies earlier answer.

Comment: This actually does help a lot. I've updated my original post to reflect the code that you submitted. How would I process the action on submit?

Comment: I updated my code to reflect the changes you provided but the page now no longer works, it won't even load. I'm confused on why this is happening.

Comment: At a glance, it looks like you are missing an `endif` for

Comment: sorry - pressed enter.

Comment: it looks like you are missing `endif` for  `if (woffice_is_user_allowed()) `